# Bouncy Castle - Certification Issue org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: certificate_unknown(46)

Tags: ssl-certificate, bouncycastle, client-certificates, fips

I am trying to make my application FIPS compliant so i have added configuration for FIPS. But I am getting below errors while building my microservice. I am getting certification issue. My certificate is already persent in my certificate directory. Any suggestions would really help.

```
   Sat Mar 26 01:11:32.721 IST 2022 [main] [o.b.jsse.provider.ProvTlsClient: INFO ] - Client raised fatal(2) certificate_unknown(46) alert: Failed to read record
org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: certificate_unknown(46)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.checkServerTrusted(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:135)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsClient$1.notifyServerCertificate(ProvTlsClient.java:360)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsUtils.processServerCertificate(TlsUtils.java:4690)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.handleServerCertificate(TlsClientProtocol.java:790)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.handleHandshakeMessage(TlsClientProtocol.java:676)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processHandshakeQueue(TlsProtocol.java:691)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processRecord(TlsProtocol.java:580)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(RecordStream.java:245)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(TlsProtocol.java:839)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.blockForHandshake(TlsProtocol.java:416)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.connect(TlsClientProtocol.java:86)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:445)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:426)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:361)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative name found matching IP address 10.14.202.191
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.HostnameUtil.checkHostname(HostnameUtil.java:69)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkEndpointID(ProvX509TrustManager.java:325)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkEndpointID(ProvX509TrustManager.java:444)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkExtendedTrust(ProvX509TrustManager.java:353)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkTrusted(ProvX509TrustManager.java:274)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(ProvX509TrustManager.java:181)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.checkServerTrusted(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:131)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Comment: **The exception message tells you** `No subject alternative name found matching IP address 10.14.202.191`. Either (1) use a name for the server that matches the certificate or (2) use a certificate that matches the name of the server.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 In which file i need to make this change, Could you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

There is a long-standing bug with HttpsURLConnection making it not work properly out-of-the-box with third-party JSSE providers. I heard that it might be mitigated in some recent JDK releases, but I'm not sure of the details.

We provide some discussion and workarounds here: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/460 .

However perhaps the most straightforward solution is to use a different HTTPS client e.g. Apache HttpClient.

Comment: I tried Set the system property jdk.tls.trustNameService to true, but this didnt work. I am trying this alternative The second (and recommended) alternative is to set a customized SSLSocketFactory on the
HttpsURLConnection. But this file is not present in my openJdk installed version.

Comment: Did you check whether the exception is still the same after setting jdk.tls.trustNameService? (I mean the inner CertificateException).

Comment: Getting this exception after setting jdk.tls.trustNameService=true  Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyFactory not available                                                                                      
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor]: Factory method 'conversionServicePostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyFactory not available